# What is the difference between `global-set-key` and `define-key global-map` in Emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, elisp

If you had two snippets:

```
(global-set-key "\C-d" delete-char)
```

and

```
(define-key global-map "\C-d" delete-char)
```

Is there a difference between the two? If so, when would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

global-set-key is defined in subr.el as:

```
(define-key (current-global-map) key command))
```

Comment: It will be nice if you can tell the difference b/w the 2

Comment: @Jaseem He just did. That's the difference between the two. `global-set-key` is a shortcut for defining a key in the value of `(current-global-map)`.

Answer (score 35):

Function `global-set-key` is an [interactive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378942/what-does-interactive-mean-in-an-emacs-lisp-function) based on `define-key` which you can invoke by typing `M-x global-set-key`. Function `define-key` is rather used in Lisp programs.

You can look up `global-set-key`'s source code with `C-h f global-set-key` to see that it only wraps `define-key`.

To answer your question, there are no significant differences between them.