# Emacs Lisp: How to use interactive (for conditional arguments)?

Tags: elisp

I want to ask a second question to the user depending on the answer to the first one.

```
(defun something (a b)
  (interactive
   (list
    (read-number "First num: ")
    (read-number "Second num: ")))
  (message "a is %s and b is %s" a b))
```

So I need a way to test the entry values :

```
(defun something-else (a &optional b)
  (interactive
   (list
    (read-number "First num: ")
    (if (< a 2)
        (read-number "Second num: "))))
  (message "a is %s" a))
```

But

```
if: Symbol's value as variable is void: a
```

Question : How can I use `interactive` in a really interactive way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defun xtest (a &optional b)
  (interactive
   (let (a b)
     (setq a (read-number "First: "))
     (if (< a 2)
         (setq b (read-number "Second: ")))
     (list a b)))

  (message "a is %s b is %s" a b))
```

Comment: Great. Added elegance to the somewhat clumsy "anonymous" interactive declaration. I've been pondering this for years, thanks!

Comment: i find using `setq` in this example more readable. The other answer is already using `let*`.

Answer (score 6):

Interpret the form in `interactive` as kind of subprogram which delivers the list of argument values as return value.
You can have local variables there with the help of a `let`-like form.

```lisp
(defun something-else (a &optional b)
  (interactive
   (let* ((a-local (read-number "First num: "))
          (b-local (when (< a-local 2)
             (read-number "Second num: "))))
     (list a-local b-local)))
  (message "a is %s, b is %s" a b))
```

In the above example `a-local` and `b-local` are variables with names of your choice wich are local to the enclosing  `let*`-form. The star in `let*` means that the evaluated expression `(read-number "First num: ")` for `a-local` is assigned to `a-local` before the expression `(when (< a-local 2) (read-number "Second num: "))` for `b-local` is evaluated.

Comment: Nice one. I ended up using this form* to avoid leaking global symbols.