# emacs, narrow-to-defun, hs-show-block

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

### I have defined the following:

```
(defun narrow-into []
  (narrow-to-defun)
  (hs-show-block))
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "zi") 'narrow-into)
```

### My Goal

The goal is that I can open up a file, hit "zi", and it will (1) narrow to the current defn and (2) open it up for editing.

### My Problem

When I try to run it, I get "Wrong type argument: commandp, narrow-into"

### Question

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: FYI there's also http://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There are additional duplicates or near duplicates of this question. For instance, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378942/what-does-interactive-mean-in-an-emacs-lisp-function).

Comment: Sorry! Did not see the duplicates. Thanks for suggestion on emacs.stackexchange!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your function interactive if you want to call it interactively.  That explains the error you are getting.  Other than that, the brackets should be parens:

```
(defun narrow-into ()
  (interactive)
  (narrow-to-defun)
  (hs-show-block))
```

Comment: (interactive) fixed it! the [] was from me using Clojure just before